# Any way to update payment method via api for facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was search and take this document.
But I can not access or any way to activity with it.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-payment-methods-info

So I have some question here.

```
GET v7.0/...?fields={fieldname_of_type_UserPaymentMethodsInfo} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

1. In text `v7.0/...?fields=*` what "..." mean ?
2. I do not see the access_token here, although it is get method. So how to authorize ?
3. Finally, this document say API payment method is read only. So, anyone know how to update payment method via api for facebook ? or another way ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. The user id? 2. That you pass an access token with all API calls, is kinda implied, I suppose. 3. Probably not possible at all.

Comment: 1. I was try with user id but i got error (Do not have this params for User node)
2. If it true, maybe facebook open a stream for this connection ? I think it imposible
3. I think no way to do that :(